# How to rotate canvas in the right way

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an image which I want to crop.

Thus, I created `canvas as overlay` with a darker background and then on mouse move I draw an `rect` on that canvas and in that rect I clear the dark background. That looks as follows:

[image]

Thus the area without background will be cropped.

My code is as follows:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var img = document.getElementById('photo');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
var update = true; // when true updates canvas
var original_source = img.src;
img.src = original_source;
var deg = 0;
var image_rotate_angle = 90;

document.getElementById('right').addEventListener("click", rotateRight, false);
document.getElementById('left').addEventListener("click", rotateLeft, false);

function rotateRight(){
 deg = deg + image_rotate_angle;
 img.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
  canvas.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
}

function rotateLeft(){
 deg = deg - image_rotate_angle;
 img.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
  canvas.style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";
}

function init() {
    img.addEventListener('load', function(){
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
    });
    
    // start the rendering loop
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// main render loop only updates if update is true
function updateCanvas(){
  if(update){
      drawCanvas();
      update = false;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// draws a rectangle with rotation 
function drawRect(){
  ctx.clearRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

// clears canvas sets filters and draws rectangles
function drawCanvas(){    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.7)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawRect()
}

// create new rect add to array 
function mouseDown(e) {
    rect = {
      startX : e.offsetX,
      startY : e.offsetY,
      w : 1,
      h : 1
    };
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; update = true; }

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        update = true;
    }
}

init();
```

```css
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  top: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  display:inline-block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
  <button id="left">Rotate Reft</button>
  <button id="right">Rotate Right</button>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;display:inline-block;">
    <img id="photo" src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg"/>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

I have also two buttons which I use to rotate the image. And there I have the problem. The solution is maybe obvious but I do not see it.

- If I draw a the rectangle and then rotate the image, I rotate the image and the canvas also, and then rectangle stays at the same place after rotating. That is what I want and that works fine.
- **The problem** is if I first rotate the image and then try to draw a rectangle. Then the rectangle isn't drawn as it should be, it goes in the opposite direction.

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/cyrjawv7/81/)

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: So, you want to rotate the image but not the canvas. Isn't it?

Comment: @LuisGar No. If I do not rotate the canvas together with image then the rectangle stays on the same place as before rotating.

Comment: So you may make an exception. If rectangle is drawed rotate all, if not, rotate only image. If I comment the line canvas.... in the functions rotateLeft and rotateRight it works well. But if want to keep the rectangle if is draw then you should make the exception

Comment: And possibly you must re rotate the piece after be cut, if it's your goal

Comment: @LuisGar And how to do that? If you comment out the lines with canvas it works fine when the canvas isn't drawn before rotating. If those lines are commented out and you draw the rectangle first and then rotate the image, the rectangle stays at the same place as before rotating. And that is what I do not want.

Comment: That I would do is to clear the rectangle so if it happens the user can do it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably just get the maths to find where the new x and y will lay, based on your image's size, but I guess it will be more manageable to actually draw everything on your canvas, and rotate its transformation matrix.

But this implies some changes in your code:

You would have to draw the image with compositing (or with 'even-odd' fill-rule, [like I already shown you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783519/adjust-canvas-background-in-javascript)).
You would also have to make your `drawCanvas` function a bit more complicated in order to rotate your *hole* only when needed (when the user clicked the "rotate" buttons).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var img = new Image();
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
var update = true; // when true updates canvas
var angle = 0;

document.getElementById('right').addEventListener("click", rotateRight, false);
document.getElementById('left').addEventListener("click", rotateLeft, false);

function rotateRight() {
  angle += Math.PI / 2;
  drawCanvas(true); // let know we're from rotate function
}

function rotateLeft() {
  angle -= Math.PI / 2;
  drawCanvas(true);
}

function init() {
  img.addEventListener('load', function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
  });

  // start the rendering loop
  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// main render loop only updates if update is true
function updateCanvas() {
  if (update) {
    drawCanvas(false); // don't rotate the rectangle here
    update = false;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}

// draws a rectangle with rotation 
function drawRect() {
  ctx.clearRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

// clears canvas sets filters and draws rectangles
function drawCanvas(fromRotate) {
  // reset the transformation matrix to its defaults
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(32, 32, 32, 0.7)';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // for the rectangle, rotate only if we are using previously set rect
  if (fromRotate) {
    // Move to center
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    // rotate by the current angle
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    // move back to what is now top right corner
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
  }
  drawRect();
  // draw the image behind the overlay
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
  // rotate the whole context every time for the image
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  // rotate by the current angle
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  // draw the image, from center
  ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2);

}

// create new rect add to array 
function mouseDown(e) {
  rect = {
    startX: e.offsetX,
    startY: e.offsetY,
    w: 1,
    h: 1
  };
  drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() {
  drag = false;
  update = true;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    rect.w = (e.offsetX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
    rect.h = (e.offsetY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
    update = true;
  }
}

init();
img.src = 'https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
```

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
  <button id="left">Rotate Reft</button>
  <button id="right">Rotate Right</button>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;display:inline-block;">

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```